# Handling IOExceptions from the Google Protocol Buffer library

Tags: java, sockets, protocol-buffers

I have some code that tries to read in a Google Protocol Buffer message from a socket in Java.  However, the mergeDelimitedFrom() method can throw an IOException if it reads in invalid data or if the socket connection is reset (and probably other reasons).  If the connection is reset I would like to exit out of the loop, but if it is just a invalid message I would like to continue running.  One thought is to just have some sort of exception counter and exit after X consecutive failures, but I was hoping to be able to figure out what type of error occurs instead of being in the dark.

This is basically the code I have:

```
while (m_Running)
{
    SomeMessage message = null;
    try
    {
        final Builder builder = SomeMessage.newBuilder();
        if (builder.mergeDelimitedFrom(m_InputStream))
        {
            message = builder.build();
        }
        else
        {
            // Google protocol buffers doesn't document it very well
            // but if mergeDelimietedFrom returns false then it has
            // reached the end of the input stream.  For a socket, no
            // more data will be coming so exit from the thread
            m_Running = false;
        }
    }
    catch (final IOException e)
    {
        // what should really be done here ???
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just don't do it. If you are reading protocol buffer objects directly off a socket, then you are effectively defining your own application protocol.  It's harder than you might think to do it right - there is a good general description of some of the problems at [On the Design of Application Protocols](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3117.txt).  It's important to understand framing - determining where one message ends and another begins.

Which leads us to some advice from the inventors of protobuf at https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/techniques.  The key piece of advice is this:

> If you want to write multiple messages to a single file or stream, it is up to you to keep track of where one message ends and the next begins.

I recommend that you decide on a framing protocol to divide the stream into messages, then write some custom socket code to handle the work or reading bytes of the sockets, dividing them into byte arrays where each byte array is known to contain exactly one message, then finally use protobuf to deserialize each message-byte-array into an object.  Guaranteed no IOException protobuf deserialization.

You'll still have to deal with IOExceptions but it will be at a lower level where you are just reading byte arrays and you'll know exactly how much data has been deserialized when the error occurs.

Also consider using something like [netty](https://netty.io) to help with the socket code.

Comment: I figured I selected a framing protocol by using mergeDelimitedFrom instead of mergeFrom as the protocol buffer library takes care of the octet-counting.  Makes me wonder why they provide that method if it isn't practical to use.  I suppose I can repeat that same logic myself by reading from the stream directly and passing a byte array to the protocol buffer library, but that seemed like reinventing the wheel a little.